# facebook sdk c# post on an user's wall

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've having a desktop application (a little game) which must be able to post comment on user's wall. Like "X won the tournement against Y and Z".

I've been reading anykind of documentation and Facebook API but I can't figure out. I have understand the way to do it : with the access token then get the information of the user using the GraphAPI and then be able to post it on his wall.

But, all the examples and the documentation haven't really help me, they are just a part of. Moreover, Facebook are changing the way to do it...so I confused.

So I would like to know how to really do it. I mean, the easiest way is find for me. That's a really small application for a few people, kind of first test application.

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: have you tried the example given for "Post Publish" at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I did not, I'll try it this week thanks

Comment: but it doesn't explain how to get the token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I made a real 360 turn by simply not using facebook SDK. Someone told me about how easy it was to post only using http requests! And with the help of another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024912/asp-net-post-to-facebook-wall)
I figured out how to do this. Here's my little simple code for doing that. Basicly, I used WPF to make a windows where the "user" would be able to connect to facebook and there's also a textBox at the top for showing me things I want...token  or web response...finally, I had 2 buttons : the first logs to facebook, the second one makes the post on facebook...there is the code in Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace HDI_WPF_WebBrowser_cs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnOnline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //dont forget to change the appID
            webOutput.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APPID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token"));
        }

        private void btnCustom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string adresseWeb = webOutput.Source.ToString();

            string token = adresseWeb.Remove(0, adresseWeb.IndexOf("#access_token=") + 14);

            token = token.Remove(token.IndexOf("&expire"));

            txtInput.Text = token;
            //dont forget to change the userID
            var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/feed?access_token=" + token);

            var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            string postData = "'access_token='" + token 
                            + "'&message=Testing testing";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            var stream = req.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            txtInput.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);            
        }
    }
}
```

and the Window1.xaml, for the WPF

```
<Window x:Class="HDI_WPF_WebBrowser_cs.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Input:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtInput" Background="Bisque" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webOutput" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnOnline" Content="Load Online" Click="btnOnline_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="btnCustom" Content="Load Custom" Click="btnCustom_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

all you have to do is creating a new WPF prodjet and write those lines in the files. Also you must change the appID and the userID. I used mine to test but it's really simple to code for danamicly find the userID.

I hope it helps you even if it isn't a solution using facebookSDK

Answer (score 1):

Doing authentication for a desktop app is more complex than for a web based app.  Since this is a "first test application", I'd highly suggest developing it as a web app using the Facebook JavaScript SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Once you can get it all working there, then going to a windows desktop app will be much easier, as now you've already got the authentication part worked out (because your desktop app will use the javascript SDK to auth the user).

But if you do want to just jump in, see: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx

Comment: you mean make a real web site or only a web site with the html pages on my computer is enough?

Comment: You can test it locally of course.  Just get used to the way to authenticate, as you'll be using that for your C# desktop app later

Comment: I tried it this way, but I can't get it working...on the JavaScript Test page of Facebook my code works, but when I try it locally it never works...I don't understand why. Do I need something more? My code is simple : download Facebook SDK C# when opening the window. then try to post something on facebook...but this step never works...basically...3 fonctions are called : FB.init, a fonction to download the SDK and finally FB.ui

Comment: It downloads the SDK but doesn't do anything after that

Comment: Be sure you're running the FB.XXXX() calls after the SDK has loaded.  Those should be inside the window.fbAsyncInit function.

Comment: I tried this...but it doesn't work either...I don't get it because it even doesn't say any kind of error....it just doesn't do anything :S that's really annoying because it's a really simple thing...

Comment: yeah, your best bet is to fill up your code with console.log("here") statements, or debugger; it

Comment: that weird, I find out that it doesn't look like going into the fbAsyncInit fonction, my console.log in it don't appear.....also...is it normal that the SDK loading fonction is after fbAsyncInit

Comment: Then you have some debugging to do.  Once you find your syntax error, I'm sure things will work as expected.

Comment: what do you suggest for debugging? I currently use notepad++ which has no debug

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer all have built-in developer tools that will help you.