# Accessing facebook for posts etc with Graph API c# unity3d

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm using C# in MonoDevelop with the Graph API to interact with users facebook pages.

I've become thoroughly confused though.

Are these the correct steps?

1. create facebook app Here : http://developers.facebook.com/
2. programmaticly get access token using app ID and app Secret.

If so how do I go from this to posting to users walls?

I've done lots of research but have been unable to find anything particularly useful.

I've tried using this [ASP.NET Post to Facebook Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024912/asp-net-post-to-facebook-wall) but Nothing ever appears on the wall.

Is there a tutorial or something that can take me through the process nice and slow?

All help or pointers appreciated.

As stated i'm working with unity3d, c# in mono and the facebook graph api.

[Edit] I'd like it to work on android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [C# Facebook library](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk). There is a sample project called facebook-aspnet-sample which shows you authentication and login. Also, have a look at this [tutorial page](http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-within-unity/) which deals with how to connect from a Unity3d game to Facebook. The tut is short but the demo project download is useful.

There are also [plugins for sale](http://gameprefabs.com/products/show/96) that enable Facebook access from Unity3d.

Comment: I'm the author of the linked tutorial and I've re-visited this. The user isn't required to copy and paste any access tokens now, it's fully automatic. Check it out: http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-unity-game-2/

Comment: Thanks Gunnar for the suggestion, I found this plugin to be the best https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16676

Answer (score 1):

after your have your FB app ready, indeed, you need to get a token. However, token is always requested in the context of a USER - and therefore user should authenticated on the website. That means that Facebook login dialog should be displayed - which will ask user if he indeed trusts the application. There are different ways to do this - here is the generic page about FB authentication: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/, and this one explains how to do this in Android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/

if you want to go with JavaScript authentication (which I personally use in MVC3 project), here is a little bit modified example from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ which does this. Remember to change app id and permissions to the ones you need.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '@EventController.FB_APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel.htm', // Path to your Channel File
            status: false, // check login status
            cookie: false, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: false  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    // get info about the user, for example
                })
                //document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                //document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            }
        });

        // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
        document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                // handle the response
                if (response.authResponse != null) {
                    // HERE IS THE TOKEN YOU CAN USE
                    var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                } else {

                }
                // AND THESE ARE THE PERMISSIONS YOU WANT YOUR APP TO REQUEST
            }, { scope: 'manage_pages,publish_stream' });
        });
    };
</script>
```

One catch here - your FB app should have your website URL (even if it is http://localhost/) in App -> Settings -> Website URL field. Also you should put channel.htm file into the root of your website with one line of code in it:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
```

Comment: This isn't really what i'm looking for as it uses web code. I think i've thrown you off by mentioning the link to the asp.net post. I didn't use the code in a web environment but in a c# Unity environment.

Comment: unless you hardcode user's access token, you cannot get it from server side code without interaction with the user. FB dialog should be always shown to the user before your app can do anything on user's behalf. If you are targeting android, there is Android SDK from FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/

Comment: Thanks, I've taken the facebook android sdk plugged it into eclipse, exported to a jar, and used IKVM to create a dll (did a google search on how to do this) I can use alongside c# and everything seems to work fine in the IDE. However I get the following error when compiling to device : "Too many heap sections"

Comment: unfortunately i can't help you with this one.

Comment: Could be a problem with Mono's garbage collector: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/236499/too-many-heap-sections-on-building-to-android.html