# (OAuthException - #1) Error validating client secret

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to implement facebook app using `C#  SDKv6` (desktop app). But when I get the access token, I'm receiving this error 
`(OAuthException - #1) Error validating client secret`.  .

This is a part of code :

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = appId,
                redirect_uri = redircct,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the client_secret:

`var oauthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient
{
   AppId = "app_id",
   AppSecret = "app_secret",
   RedirectUri = new Uri("http://redirecturi.com")
};`

`dynamic result = oauthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken("code");
var accessToken = result.access_token;`

[Here is the reference](http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-making-requests)

[and a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236651/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-trouble-getting-me-accounts)